# Linux to windows commands | Angular Setup with SpringBoot

Tags: angular, spring-boot, batch-file, cmd, sh

I was going through the tutorial: https://github.com/dsyer/spring-boot-angular

to setup angular project with Spring Boot. The tutorial used certain scripts to automate the build process. Like the followings:

1.

```
$ cat > npm
#!/bin/sh
cd $(dirname $0)
PATH="$PWD/node/":$PATH
node "node/node_modules/npm/bin/npm-cli.js" "$@"
$ chmod +x npm
```

2.

```
$ cat > ng
#!/bin/sh
cd $(dirname $0)
PATH="$PWD/node/":"$PWD":$PATH
node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng "$@"
$ chmod +x ng
$ ./ng --version
```

3.

```
$ cat client/.gitignore >> .gitignore
$ rm -rf client/node* client/src/favicon.ico client/.gitignore client/.git
$ sed -i '/node_/anode/' .gitignore
$ cp -rf client/* .
$ cp client/.??* .
$ rm -rf client
$ sed -i -e 's,dist/client,target/classes/static,' angular.json
```

I suppose these are sh scripts and can run in linux environment. How to translate these scripts to windows environment. Or, can anyone point me to the windows version of the tutorial.

Comment: hmmmm.... `cat` = `type` `rm` = `rm` `cp` = `copy` you will not find a straight forward tool like `sed` in windows, probably have to use `cscript` but why do you want to do this? why not just install somethig like `cygwin` ? ... anyway, the question is actually offtopic here on SO.

Comment: these are very basic commands which you can easily do in windows os like copy,delete,change permissions,setting path in environment variables.

Answer (score 0):

It may be a good idea to use something like [`busybox-w32`](https://frippery.org/busybox/) and just run the scripts as-is with minimal modifications.

I omitted duplicate commands. Please try to figure out how everything works rather than just copy-pasting my submission - it may be possible that I messed up something.

Other than that, here goes:

Unix:

```
$ cat > npm
```

Windows:

```
copy CON npm.bat
```

(end file input with `ENTER`, `CTRL+Z`, `ENTER`)

Although it may be simpler to do

```
notepad npm.bat
```

since it is always installed with the OS.

Unix:

```
#!/bin/sh
```

Windows:

does not support shebangs. 
You need to name your script with `.bat` or `.cmd` extension.
This line needs to be ommited.
Comments are started with `rem`

Unix:

```
cd $(dirname $0)
```

Windows:

```
cd %~dp0
```

Run `call /?` for details on what it means.

Unix:

```
PATH="$PWD/node/":$PATH
```

Windows:

```
set path=%cd%\node;%path%
```

see `set /?` and `path /?`

Unix:

```
node "node/node_modules/npm/bin/npm-cli.js" "$@"
```

Windows:

```
node "node\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js" %*
```

You will need to press `ENTER`, `Ctrl+Z`, `ENTER` here if you did `copy CON` thing

Unix:

```
$ chmod +x npm
```

Windows:

No action required. In Windows all files ending with `.bat` and `.cmd` are executable by default and people very rarely bother with access rights at all.

Unix:

```
$ ./ng --version
```

Windows:

```
ng --version
```

Windows executes files from current directory by default

Unix:

```
$ cat client/.gitignore >> .gitignore
```

Windows:

```
type client\.gitignore >> .gitignore
```

Unix:

```
$ rm -rf client/node* client/src/favicon.ico client/.gitignore client/.git
```

Windows:

```
rd /s /q "client\node*"
del /y "clientsrc\favicon.ico"
del /y "client\.gitignore"
del /y "client\.git"
```

Windows does not support deleting or copying multiple files with one command

Unix:

```
$ sed -i '/node_/anode/' .gitignore
```

Windows:

You can either download and install [`sed for windows`](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/sed.htm) or open `notepad` and use `Replace` command from its menu. It does not support regular expressions.

Unix:

```
$ cp -rf client/* .
```

Windows:

```
xcopy /S /E /I /Y "client\*" .\
```

you may also use `robocopy`, see `robocopy /?` and `xcopy /?`

Unix:

```
$ cp client/.??* .
```

Windows:

```
copy /y "client\.*" .
```

I'm not sure what exactly they try to accomplish with this but if this copies only files that have exactly two or more characters this may be a little tricky in windows since `??` is interpreted as `*` by the command processor. You would need a `for` loop, then check `if` `%variable:~3:1%` is empty or something like that. It may be easier to fully rework this command based on context. See `for /?`, `if /?`, `set /?` and/or [this site](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-substring.html)